# "Верь (—) не верь": нужно ли тире или дефис?

Tags: пунктуация

Выражения типа "верь (—) не верь", "кричи (—) не кричи". Просится дефис или тире, но как их ставить? Как вообще их правильно писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Не являются однородными и не разделяются запятой:** 
– осложненные простые сказуемые, выраженные двумя разными
глаголами в одинаковой форме, первый из которых не обозначает отдельного действия, а лишь указывает на движение, состояние, целью которого является другое действие, выраженное вторым глаголом: Хорошо, 
сядем поговорим (Айтм.); Зайду проведаю (Л. Т.); Я пойду поищу его
(Ч.); 
– устойчивые выражения: Поговорим о том о сем; За все про все ее
бранят (Кр.); 
– **осложненные члены предложения, выраженные двумя повторяющимися одинаковыми формами одного и того же слова, соединенные
частицами так или не**: *работать так работать, придут так придут, 
спел так спел, утром так утром, хочешь не хочешь, кричи не кричи, 
страшно не страшно: О чем спор? Работать так работать; Что же
делать? Искать так искать! (М. П.);* ***Кричи не кричи, а никто здесь не
слышит; Хочешь не хочешь, а идти надо.*** [Справочник по русской пунктуации](http://www.bsu.by/Cache/pdf/218053.pdf)

**Так что ни тире, ни запятую в таких выражениях ставить не нужно**.